# SQL SERVER: Update dB field when a checkbox is checked by the user

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

i have a field in a table called isBilled. isBilled is always false in the table until the user checks the field on the page. So, when the user checks this box i want to verify that it is checked and change it in the dB field via stored procedure and update that field. My code for checking if the box is checked is:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[prcCheckIsBilledInTestAssignmentsTable] (@isBilled as bit, @TestAssignmentID as int) AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF(SELECT isBilled FROM tblTT_TestAssignments WHERE TestAssignmentID = @TestAssignmentID) = 1
    BEGIN
        select 1 as 'TRUE'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        select 0 as 'FALSE'
    END
END
```

Comment: I didn't find any update statement. Can you show ?

Comment: Sorry, was working on it after i posted. Wasnt really sure where to place it in the statement....

    BEGIN
    UPDATE tblTT_TestAssignments
    SET isBilled = 1
    WHERE TestAssignmentID = @TestAssignmentID AND isBilled = 0
 END